# From a set of all possible combinations drawing 3 items out of 10, how to fetch the unselected items corresponding to each combination?

Tags: r, statistics, combinations, sampling

I have data from 10 samples, which appear to show a normal distribution. I want to remove 3 samples that are representative of the group for more analysis, while leaving the remaining 7 samples also representative of the original group (as much as possible). I don't know which three samples are best to take, so I was thinking one way to do this in R would be to find the combination with the minimum difference to mean and SD to the original and remaining group:

1. List every possible combination of 3 samples I could take
2. For each combination calculate the mean and SD of both these three samples, and the remaining 7 samples
3. There would now be three means and three SDs, the means and SDs of the 3-group and 7-group plus the mean and SD of the original 10-group. I would generate an SD of the three means, and a SD of the three SDs
4. Each combination now has two values associated with it, the SD of the means, and an SD of the SDs
5. These values for each combination could be graphed, and whichever point is closest to the origin is my best combination.

For step 1 I make a vector with my values then use combn to give me all combinations without repetition, then add means and SDs

```
x <- c(5, 20, 30, 32, 25, 40, 29, 33, 10, 24)
df1 = t(combn(x,3))
df1$mean = rowMeans(df1)
df1$row_std = rowSds(as.matrix(df1[,c(1,2,3)]))
```

Step 3 and 4 seems just a straightforward moving the means and SDs another dataframe and making new means and SDs from these values in the same way, then I find the combination with the lowest values.

My problem is in step 2, how can I fetch the corresponding unselected items for each combination?

I was wondering perhaps if I generate a matrix with all ten items on every row, then subtract the matrix of all combinations row by row, I could be left with a matrix of the unselected values, but I really can't work out how to do this. For just means I could add up each combination and subtract each one from a total of the 10, then average, but of course not possible for SD.

Thanks in advance